# Automating inbox zero with the org agenda?

Tags: org-mode, email, mu4e

**Q**: how can I automate inbox zero with my `org-mode` agenda by getting linked, deadlined reminders to emails that need a reply?

I get a lot of email, and try to stay at
[inbox zero](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/inbox-zero), but I don't always want to reply to an email
immediately upon reading it.  I do, however, want to remind myself
that I need to reply.

I'm hoping to automate this recurring use pattern, described here in excruciating detail:

1. open up inbox (using `mu4e`)
2. mark an email for reply with `org-store-link`
3. refile that message to All Mail (or wherever; it's a gmail account)
4. go to my main agenda file (call it `agenda.org`)
5. go to the `* EMAIL` section
6. use `org-insert-link` to create a new entry `** Respond to XXXX`
7. set a deadline for later in the day (or tomorrow, or whenever)

The end product is a series of entries in the `EMAIL` section,
each linked to a specific email that needs a reply, and each with
a defined deadline so that it will show up in my agenda view to
remind me.  I'm just not sure how to automate the whole thing.

*Does something like this already exist and I just don't know about
it?  If not, how would one implement it?*

PS: I'm loosely aware of
[`mu4e` actions](http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Actions.html#Actions),
which I expect would be the starting point, but it's also
package-specific and wouldn't apply to, say, `gnus`.

Comment: It seems to me that org-capture would be the most natural solution. There's an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15772459/113848), which does half of what you want. What's missing is refiling the message and adding a deadline.

Comment: @legoscia: thanks for the suggestion.  I ended up rolling my own and got something that seems to do everything I'm looking for.  Hopefully it doesn't turn out to be too fragile.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that it's pretty straightforward to put this function together, although there's a bunch of housekeeping to keep the buffers tidy.  The following command words with `mu4e` in both its `headers` and `view` modes.  It's minimally tested at this point, but seems to be working in the main.  Note that it hard codes a few things such as the section heading and the specific file.

```el
(defun mu4e-msg-to-agenda (arg)
  "Refile a message and add a entry in the agenda file with a
deadline.  Default deadline is today.  With one prefix, deadline
is tomorrow.  With two prefixes, select the deadline."
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((file (car org-agenda-files))
        (sec  "^* EMAIL\\s-*$")
        (msg  (mu4e-message-at-point)))
    (when msg
      ;; put the message in the agenda
      (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
        (save-excursion
          ;; find header section
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (when (re-search-forward sec nil t)
            (let ((org-M-RET-may-split-line)
                  (lev (org-outline-level))
                  (folded-p (invisible-p (point-at-eol))))
              ;; place the subheader
              (when folded-p (show-branches))    ; unfold if necessary
              (org-end-of-meta-data-and-drawers) ; skip property drawer
              (org-insert-todo-heading 1)        ; insert a todo heading
              (when (= (org-outline-level) lev)  ; demote if necessary
                (org-do-demote))
              ;; insert message and add deadline
              (insert (concat "respond to "
                              "[[mu4e:msgid:"
                              (plist-get msg :message-id) "]["
                              (caar (plist-get msg :from)) "]] "))
              (org-deadline nil
                            (cond ((= arg 1) (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d"))
                                  ((= arg 4) "+1d")))
              ;; refold as necessary
              (if folded-p
                  (progn
                    (org-up-heading-safe)
                    (hide-subtree))
                (hide-entry))))))
      ;; refile the message and update
      (cond ((eq major-mode 'mu4e-view-mode)
             (mu4e-view-mark-for-refile))
            ((eq major-mode 'mu4e-headers-mode)
             (mu4e-headers-mark-for-refile)))
      (message "Refiled and added to the agenda for %s"
               (cond ((= arg 1) "today")
                     ((= arg 4) "tomorrow")
                     (t         "later"))))))
```